# Mobile optimising iframes and form fields

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, mobile, iframe

I'm just working on optimising my website for mobile, you can see it here:

http://www.carladessi.com

The pages I'm having issues with are the blog page and the contact us page. The blog page uses embedded iframes from gist, they work fine on desktop sites but on mobile they are way too wide and don't shrink to fit. Also with the contact page, the form fields go off the page when it's small.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Twitter Bootstrap for your form. They do a great job of responsively treating form elements for different screen sizes. You can download it here:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

If you do not have access to the code that you are iFraming in for the blog, then you will not be able to make it more user-friendly on a mobile device. I would suggest contacting the creator and asking if they can send you the content through a web service instead of using an iFrame.